# How to catch Value of variable to new different Variable from 1 line?

Tags: perl

I hv 3 words "This is Test" in 1 line

I don't know how to catch the Value of variable to new Variable in 1 line,
without create a new variable for each words or using ARGV.

```html
$words = "This is Test";

#what is in here?

print "$Word1 $Word2 $Word3\n";
```

It would be easy if i just put, But this isn't on 1 line.

```html
$Word1 = "This";
$Word2 = "is";
$Word3 = "Test";
print "$Word1 $Word2 $Word3\n";
```

Pls, anyone help me fix the codes!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` function to break apart the string, using a space as the delimiter. You can assign the results into three variables all at once.

```
($Word1, $Word2, $Word3) = split(' ', $words);
```

Comment: You should also be aware that `split` normally takes a RegEx as a delimiter. Using a single space is special syntax which will split on any amount of whitespace, and also strip leading and trailing space, ie. `split(' ', '  one two    three    ')` will return the list `('one', 'two', 'three')`